# Yii2 afterDelete won't get called

Tags: php, yii2

I have the user page in my application.When i delete the user in user screen the same user records are want to be deleted in other table also.I have done the createCommand.But the function itself won't get called.I have the UserController and User model.

**Controller:**

```
public function actionDelete($id)
{
    $user=$this->findModel($id)->delete();  
    return $this->redirect(['index']);
}
```

**Model:**

```
public function afterDelete()
    {
    //print"<script>alert('delete')</script>";
        $id = $this->id;
        parent::afterDelete();
        $connection     = Yii::$app->getDb();
        $tshirtaccessTable  = TshirtAccess::tableName();
        $userRoleTable      = UserRole::tableName();

        $transaction    = $connection->beginTransaction();
        try {
            $sql1 = "DELETE FROM ".$tshirtaccessTable." WHERE userid=:userid";
            $sql2 = "DELETE FROM ".$userRoleTable." WHERE userid=:userid";

            $connection->createCommand($sql1)->bindValue(':userid',$id)->execute();
            $connection->createCommand($sql2)->bindValue(':userid',$id)->execute();

            $transaction->commit();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $transaction->rollBack();
            //throw $e;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If afterDelete() is called (put an echo inside this function or use the debugger), check if $sql commands throw an exception and transaction is rolled back (so delete are not executed).

Comment: no its not coming to this function only..i given alert and echo and checked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your afterDelete is not getting called because you are executing SQL query directly to perform delete action.
whereas you have written afterDelete in your model.

in order to get this work, you need to find and delete the object of the model.

```
$model = TshirtAccess::find()->where(['userid' => $user_id])->one(); //all()
$model->delete(); // this will trigger your afterDelete function and execute your code.
```

this will resolve your issue.

Comment: i given alert inside the afterDelete function.But it is not coming.Whatever i kept inside function will work..

Comment: afterDelete function will call automatically know?or i need to call manually?

Comment: I controller i have delete function which is actionDelete

Comment: try to understand, the afterDelete function will get called automatically on executing $model->delete(); 
actionDelete is some thing totally different. it is being called for action, and the model corresponding to table, has to have the afterDelete() and contains your code to be executed automatically. 
please post your controller code for better clarification.

Comment: yes i knew that..what i am telling is '$model->delete()' is in the actionDelete.That is already there.i no need to add.I ll add the controller code also.

Comment: remove parent::afterDelete(); and try again

Comment: i just tried out the following and it is working.
controller:
public function actionTest1() {
        $user =  Users::findOne(359)->delete();
        
    }
model:
public function afterDelete() {
        $id = $this->id;
        die($id);
    }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148602/discussion-between-gunnrryy-and-lalithkumar).